# How to integrate an HID USB Controller?

Tags: c++, hid, gamecontroller

I'm at a standstill. I have this non-standard game controller which I would like to integrate into an application. It has three joysticks, and fifteen possible buttons.

It is an HID compliant USB-connected controller, operating primarily on Windows, but at some point I will have to port it over to Android as well. I want to monitor for inputs in my C++ project, and then use those inputs. So for example, with the joysticks I will be monitoring the axis value, and buttons I will be monitoring the boolean.

**How do I find the input variable (if any) for the joysticks and buttons, and then link them to the code?** I've used XInput for compatible controllers before, so I have some familiarity with that system.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way could be by getting the key code. You can easily search in google for html key codes and if you use the joystick it should say what its code is

Comment: I've tried that, but no keycode appears for the controller input. I know it is working from testing it via properties window, but it is not registering in the browser event keycode.

Comment: If you know the model you may be able to search thekeycodes